# Is there a way to identify audio or image files in java, without use the file extension?

Tags: java, file

Supposing new audio and image types will be created, I want my filter to separate the images and audio files. Is there a way to recognize then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short ... no.

In long, assuming we have *no* knowledge of media files and types [ie no knowledge of file extensions, data format, etc], the only means to identify a kind of file is to probe its data and identify it - which requires intimate knowledge of the media format, something we do not have.

However, if our operating system contains these media files, chances are someone within the system *does* know how to open or manipulate them. Therefore it is logical to assume this application would register the media type [and other metadata such as file extension, default player, etc] with the system.

So if you are keen on remaining dynamic, you should probably find a means of communicating with the underlying system for media events [such as when a new media format is encountered and registered].

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the files to detect the actual media type. Look at [Java Mime Magic Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/). It is similar to the `file` command under unix.

Comment: is there a generic method to say if it is an audio or image, independent of the extension?

Comment: the purpose of this lib is to not rely upon the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you only exception-based solution i.e. try to read each file with ImageIO and if exception is thrown then it's not an image file. But it's a bad solution.

You'd better find an opportunity to distinguish them in some other more logical way.

Comment: +1 I liked. If new types of image appear, the ImageIO will be updated, so my app. I'll wait more opinions.

Comment: But ImageIO doesn't recognize *all* types of images that exist even now... call `ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()` / `getReaderMIMETypes()` to see which are supported.  You can add plugins to support new image types, but you'd have to know the format beforehand.